# How to add text in pop up window in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to test a website using selenium(with java). On my website, there is an option to add a new class. When we click on the add new option button, a pop-up window will come and we can enter our new class name. But using selenium I cannot enter alphabets into the pop-up window. I can only enter numbers in that field. The field accept both alphabets and numbers when we enter the data manually. How can I add alphabets to the pop window in selenium?

Here I attach my code below :

```
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"modal-add\"]")));
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"class\"]")).sendKeys("LKG");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section/div/div[3]/div/div/form/div[2]/button[2]")).click
```

screenshot of the field - [Class_field_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIbid.png)

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML

Comment: Can you enter alphanumeric symbols manualy? Maybe there is a restriction on the input field.

Comment: since you can type only numbers, check if the input is type="number". in that case, your are doing false-testing.

Comment: The field accept both alphabets and numbers when we enter the data manually

Comment: Post the page source of that popup.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you are not able to add alphabets in textfield using sendkeys function. I haven't heard this type of issue before please confirm that either that field accept alphabets or not. if that feild accept alphabets then try using another way like javascript executor to send text as mentioned below

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
js.executeScript("$('#id').val("sendtext")");
```

Comment: Sir, can you please send me an example using the above mentioned code

Comment: I have already mentioned the complete example. all you need to do is just put the id of input field after # and add what you want to send in val("type here to send")

Comment: Sorry, it's not working I tried this way -  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;  
  js.executeScript("$('section').val("New Class")");

Comment: You need to put # before section if its is id or if it is className put dot . before section like js.executeScript("$('#section').val("New Class")");

Comment: I tried this way but it's not working -     JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;  
   js.executeScript("$('#section').val('New Class')");

Comment: could you please provide the html of the popup ?

Comment: <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal-add" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-modal="true" style="padding-right: 17px; display: block;">

Comment: Hi, please provide the complete html of popup including the input text field html.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try Clipboard class for copy and paste string value in class field ? Make sure you click first in class text field and then use paste code. As you say by keyboard you are able to enter alphabet so try to use keys class too.In both cases your keyboard is going to use so may be it helps.